# Batch processing of files that have changed

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

I have an application which has a `Timer` and a `FileSystemWatcher` in it for batch processing of changed files every 5 minutes for instance.

The `FileSystemWatcher` raises event when a file is changed and the file path is added to a `Queue`, only after checking if it already exists in the queue or not.

When the `Timer` ticks it iterates through the queue, popping each item and processing it; until the queue is empty.

My questions are:

- Am I trying to solve this problem correctly and using the correct datatypes?
- Do I need to worry about concurrent access to the `Queue`? If so, how should I deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED :** 
Question 1: I thinks the approach and object you are using for batch processing of files is appropriate as i see. Note: The time interval for processing the changes should be fair enough so that you don't run into any file lock issues or something similar.

Question 2: If the queue is accessed from the same instance then i don't see any issues. You experience locking issues normally with collections if you are accessing it from differnet threads, which is not the case here.

Then again if you encounter that issue or worried for the queue access and thread safety, I would suggest using - [Concurrent Collection types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287108%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Your question: "What happens if the Timer ticks at the same time that the FileSystemWatcher adds a changed file?" - Answer to this question is - "You will not get any exception or errors and the file changes add item will apprear on next timer tick for processing."

Comment: I don't understand the first statement of answer 1 or what you mean by answer 2 - could you please expand. What happens if the `Timer` ticks at the same time that the `FileSystemWatcher` adds a changed file?

Comment: Given that I've now learned that Timers elapse and FileSystemWatchers notify on any thread in the Thread pool, there could be some concurrent editing that will need to be handled.

Comment: If any newly added item is not processed in the current executing batch will get processed in next batch and for the concurrent editing from the queue as i suggested earlier use concurrent collection types and you will not having any accessing or locking issues. "Concurrent collection types is solution to 'Concurrent editing' issue".